# Database Design for a University.Database Design Question

Tags: database, database-design, ms-access-2010

I am new to database design. I am designing a database for a department in a university.
There is no relational database and I have to design in from the scratch. I have to use Microsoft Access for the database.

---

Here is my model and following is some explanation about the tables (entities).

```
A student can register in many programs.
A program can have many students.
A program can have many levels.
A program can have many courses.
A course can be in many programs
A student can take many courses.
A course can have many programs.
A course can have many sections.
A course can have many groups.
A course can be taken in many semesters.
```

(I am not sure If I am right)

---

My Problems:

I am not sure if it is OK to have composite keys that I created.
I do not know where should I put the grade for each course. Should I create a new table? I assume it is an entity, but how can I connect a grade with student number and course code.
I do not know how to related courses and programs tables.

Could you please check this model and write your idea and solutions.[image]

Comment: What is a grade? Is it a definition of what a pass is, or is it the mark a student got for a given student_course_registration row? The answer to that should tell you where to put it.

Comment: I need to save the mark for each course that a student takes, the pass or fail data and if it is A ,A+,A- , and etc.

Answer (score 0):

First unless space is tight let access provide primary keys for the tables.  You don't control the course codes, semester codes, etc.  when the university redesigns there course codes having a database primary key lets the database distinguish between two courses with the same code and other such problems.
Next your table structure is fine but add a gradetypes table including types like pass/fail, audit, & incomplete. set up a one to many relationship between the gradetypes table and the student course registration table.
Add gradetype column (linked to gradetypes) & gradevalue colum (number) to the student course registration table.  these two columns provide a simple way to represent a students grade and a student's grade naturally fits in the student course registration table.
with this solution, you need to come up with a code that assigns a number (gradevalue) representing each student's grade in each course type.  For instance in a  pass/fail course 0 is fail and 1 is pass.  If you cannot come up with such a code just replace the gradetype and gradevalue columns with a link to a StudentCourseRegistrationGrade table designed to describe the more complicated relationship.

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to Stack Overflow. We don't much like images for schema definitions - they are hard to work with, and we end up replicating the content in text.

It seems like your design doesn't quite reflect the requirements you describe.

The table `student_semester_registrations` suggests that students sign up for a semester within a program. I can't find that in your requirements.

You don't capture `A program can have many levels`, `A program can have many courses` or `A course can be in many programs`, `A course can have many programs`,
`A course can have many sections`, `A course can have many groups`.

To answer your questions:

> where should I put the grade for each course

The grade is an attribute of the student's participation in a course. So it belongs in `student_course_registration`. The relationship between that participation and "semester" is not clearly present in your problem definition "can be taken" does not suggest that a student can enroll just for one semester in a course. Instead, it suggests that there is a many-to-many relationship between course and semester (i.e. a `course_semesters` join table).

```
is (it) OK to have composite keys
```

Yes, it is, as long as you are confident that the keys you have created are invariant.

```
I do not know how to related courses and programs tables.
```

The requirements suggest a many-to-many relationship (a course belongs to 1 or more programs, a program has 1 or more courses). You capture this via a join table `programs_courses`, with foreign keys to course and program.